# Install python-dev on CentOS 7 with no root privileges

Tags: python, gcc, centos, cython, centos7

I have Python 2.7 installed on a CentOS 7 system and now I'm trying to make Cython work. The problem is, it can't find `Python.h` which, I believe, is because `python-dev` is not installed. Is there a way to install `python-dev` on CentOS with no root privileges?